# aci-connector-linux pod for Azure AKS in CrashLoopBackOff status

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, azure-cli

I am having an issue when trying to setup **Virtual Nodes** for **Azure Kubernetes cluster** using **Terraform**.

When I check the pod for the aci-connector-linux, I get the below error:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                    ----     -------
  Normal   Pulled   41m (x50 over 4h26m)    kubelet  Container image "mcr.microsoft.com/oss/virtual-kubelet/virtual-kubelet:1.4.1" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff  68s (x1222 over 4h26m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

I've also granted the System Assigned identity of the Azure Kubernetes Cluster the required contributor role using the documentation here - https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/aci_connector_linux/main.tf but I'm still getting CrashLoopBackOff status error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it.

The issue was caused by the Outdated documentation for `aci-connector-linux` here - https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/aci_connector_linux/main.tf which assigns the role to the Managed identity of the Azure Kubernetes cluster

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Azure Kubernetes Service creates Node resource group which is separate from the resource group for the Kubernetes Cluster. Within the Node resource group, AKS creates a Managed Identity for the `aci-connector-linux`. The name of the Node resource group is usually `MC_<KubernetesResourceGroupName_KubernetesServiceName-KubernetesResourceGroupLocation>`, so if your **KubernetesResourceGroupName** is `MyResourceGroup` and if the **KubernetesServiceName** is `my-test-cluster` and if the **KubernetesResourceGroupLocation** `westeurope`, then the Node resource group will be `MC_MyResourceGroup_my-test-cluster_westeurope`. You can view the resources in the Azure Portal under Resource Groups.

Next, you can view the root cause of the issue by viewing the logs of the `aci-connector-linux` pod using the command:

```
kubectl logs aci-connector-linux-577bf54d75-qm9kl -n kube-system
```

And you will an output like this:

> time="2022-06-29T15:23:38Z" level=fatal msg="error initializing provider azure: error setting up network profile: error while looking up subnet: api call to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/0237fb7-7530-43ba-96ae-927yhfad80d1/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet/subnets/k8s-aci-node-pool-subnet?api-version=2018-08-01: got HTTP response status code 403 error code "AuthorizationFailed": The client '560df3e9b-9f64-4faf-aa7c-6tdg779f81c7' with object id '560df3e9b-9f64-4faf-aa7c-6tdg779f81c7' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/read' over scope '/subscriptions/0237fb7-7530-43ba-96ae-927yhfad80d1/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet/subnets/k8s-aci-node-pool-subnet' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."

You can fix this in **Terraform** using the code below:

```
# Get subnet ID
data "azurerm_subnet" "k8s_aci" {
  name                 = "k8s-aci-node-pool-uat-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = "sparkle-uat-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

# Get the Identity of a service principal
data "azuread_service_principal" "aks_aci_identity" {
  display_name = "aciconnectorlinux-${var.kubernetes_cluster_name}"
  depends_on = [module.kubernetes_service_uat]
}

# Assign role to aci identity
module "role_assignment_aci_nodepool_subnet" {
  source = "../../../modules/azure/role-assignment"

  role_assignment_scope        = data.azurerm_subnet.k8s_aci.id
  role_definition_name         = var.role_definition_name.net-contrib
  role_assignment_principal_id = data.azuread_service_principal.aks_aci_identity.id
}
```

You can also achieve this using the Azure CLI command below:

```
az role assignment create --assignee <Object (principal) ID> --role "Network Contributor" --scope <subnet-id>
```

**Note**: The **Object (principal) ID** is the ID that you obtained in the error message.

An example is this:

```
az role assignment create --assignee 560df3e9b-9f64-4faf-aa7c-6tdg779f81c7 --role "Network Contributor" --scope /subscriptions/0237fb7-7530-43ba-96ae-927yhfad80d1/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet/subnets/k8s-aci-node-pool-subnet
```

**Resources**:

[Aci connector linux should export the identity associated to its addon](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9733)

[Using Terraform to create an AKS cluster with "SystemAssigned" identity and aci_connector_linux profile enabled does not result in a creation of a virtual node](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1894)

[Azure Kubernetes Service Tutorial: How to Integrate AKS with Azure Container Instances](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-cvo-blg-azure-kubernetes-service-tutorial-integrate-aks-with-aci)

[Fail to configure a load balancer (AKS)](https://docs.microfocus.com/doc/SMAX/2021.05/AKSFailToPatchLB)